# Separate states per child React component with useSelector hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have an app which loads images and I want to click a thumbs-up icon to 'Like' and image or a trash-can icon to delete an image. While the call to the backend is pending I want to show a spinner instead of the icon. When fetching the loading state of my calls from the store all my components get updated simultaneously instead of just targeting the current component I am clicking on

Which looks like this (spinner appears after clicking the like button)

[image]

As you can see the spinner appears on each `ImageCard`!!!

**ImageCard.tsx**

```
export function ImageCard({ image }: ImageProp): ReactElement {
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(image.tags.includes(TAGS.FAV));
    const imageLikeState = useSelector(likeImagePending);
    const imageDeleteState = useSelector(deleteImagePending);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const like = (public_id: string, tag: string) => {
        setLiked(!liked);
        dispatch(toggleLiked(public_id, tag));
    };
    const deleteImage = (public_id: string) => {
        dispatch(deleteImageCall(public_id));
    };

    return (
        <div className="card mb-5 portfolio-item">
            <div className="card-image">
                <img className="image" src={image.secure_url} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="card-button-container">
                {!imageDeleteState && (
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        onClick={() => deleteImage(image.public_id)}
                        icon={trashRegular}
                        size="lg"
                        color="#FF4545"
                    />
                )}

                {imageDeleteState && <img className="spinner" src={Spinner} alt="Loading Spinner" />}

                <div className="rating-container">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={starRegular} size="lg" color="#FF9529" />
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={starRegular} size="lg" color="#FF9529" />
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={starRegular} size="lg" color="#FF9529" />
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={starRegular} size="lg" color="#FF9529" />
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={starRegular} size="lg" color="#FF9529" />
                </div>

                {!imageLikeState && (
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        onClick={() => like(image.public_id, TAGS.FAV)}
                        icon={liked ? heartSolid : heartOutline}
                        size="lg"
                        color="#1A8CC9"
                    />
                )}

                {imageLikeState && <img className="spinner" src={Spinner} alt="Loading Spinner" />}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const imageLikeState = useSelector(likeImagePending);
const imageDeleteState = useSelector(deleteImagePending);
```

Based on this, it looks like you have a selector that tells you if *any* image is pending.  What you want is a selector that tells you if a *specific* image id is pending.

The component code should look like this

```
const imageLikeState = useSelector(likeImagePending(image.public_id));
const imageDeleteState = useSelector(deleteImagePending(image.public_id));
```

That means you'll need to change the selector and probably the redux state as well.  If you are currently storing a `boolean` value of `isLikePending`, a simple solution is to change it so that the value stored in your redux state is the numeric id of the image which is pending, or `false` if none are pending.

Your selector would check if the id that you are passing in the arguments matches the pending id and return a `boolean`.

```
const isLikePending = (id) => (state) => {
   return state.isLikePending === id;
}
```